# How to run a specific.js file through terminal in cypress?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, cypress

If I use the command **npx cypress run** all the test cases run perfectly.

I am getting the below error:

C:\Users\Krina Modi\Documents\CypressWorkshop> **npx cypress run --spec "cypress\cypress\integration\2-advanced-examples\actions.spec.js"**

Can't run because no spec files were found.

We searched for any files matching this glob pattern:

cypress\cypress\integration\2-advanced-examples\actions.spec.js

Relative to the project root folder:

C:\Users\Krina Modi\Documents\CypressWorkshop

**Here is an image of my actual path**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The command looks ok from the info in explorer, but `/CypressWorkshop/cypress/cypress/` may be causing the problem. Where is your `cypress.json` file?

I would remove the 2nd `/cypress` folder, move everything from `/cypress/cypress` down to `/cypress` and remove the empty folder.

Comment: Here is the path of .json - \CypressWorkshop\cypress\cypress.json

Comment: So, that's where the Cypress runner thinks the project root is, but it then is confused by the extra cypress folder between project root and the integration folder.

Comment: I have remove 2nd cypress folder, still same error.

Comment: Well, it should now show the different path in the error message?

Comment: You can try a glob pattern `npx cypress run --spec "**\actions.spec.js"` which may get around any path problems, since `**` matches any path of any length. Be careful if you have multiple `action.spec.js`